# How to work with a boss who procrastinates and provides no opinion until the last moment?

Tags: professionalism, time-management, seniority, sales, procrastination

I work in India in healthcare sales.

I am very goal-oriented and a person who is particular with my work. I don't like the idea of deadlines and my work is finished way before the deadline. For the same, I like to plan and work ahead of time. If my plan doesn't work out, I still have a lot of time to revise, and if required, re-revise my plan.

On the contrary, my boss is laid back and likes to challenge the deadline. Therefore, he does not take any of my work on priority as he has other things to do. Therefore, he takes my plans and ideas on the last moment (which probably I made a long time back), and asks me to revise the plans at the last moment which I dislike.

I try to remind him almost everyday about a pending task, but he straightforward ignores and provides me with no opinion until the deadline.

The last time, this happened, I had to cancel a plan which I was planning for almost 10 days.

My patience is wearing thin and I don't know what to do? Please advice for the same.

P.S - I in no way am undermining what my boss is doing as he has a lot of things to do, but in my success is his success, therefore, would want clarity.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - That's a very strange comment. If I could do that, why would I post my question on this portal.

Comment: This might be a case of personalities clashing. While finding a workable middle ground is theoretically possible, it seems unlikely you will be able to change the way your boss works

Comment: If your boss knew about this site he would probably post a question titled "How to work with a fussbudget employee who rushes ahead of every plan and demands details for tasks that aren't even scheduled for weeks yet?"

Comment: Does your boss treat your coworkers the same way ?

Answer (score 5):

Several approaches. First one: Relax.

If some project needs to be completed until the 20th, you don't gain anything substantial if you rush it and complete it on the 10th. And if your boss demands some changes on the 19th, you can always push back and tell him you can't complete it until the deadline, because of short notice. This is not your problem, remember that. Let your boss learn from his own mistakes, don't be afraid to miss deadlines if someone else does not perform.

Second: Make your bosses life easier. Don't pile a lot of information onto him and ask for "opionion". Give him what he needs to work as fast and effective as possible. Easy tasks don't get delayed, they get tackled immediately, because they are fun.

Third: Frame challenge. Only because boss doesn't complete your requests immediately does not mean he "procastrinates". It's much more probable that he has a lot of time critical tasks on his plate and needs to prioritize.

Comment: As I mentioned, I work in sales. An order is expected by the next 2 weeks. My plan is to travel to the client's place in this week to discuss the challenges. I have sent my plan to my boss for approval. Approval was not received, travel is delayed, order is delayed. Result will be added pressure on the boss and subsequently on me. I want to excel at my job, I don't know about my boss. I don't mind to earn incentives, why would my boss mind if he has to put in some extra work !

Comment: @ShravanKarmarkar that's what this line from the answer is for: "you can always push back and tell him you can't complete it until the deadline, because of short notice. *This is not your problem, remember that.* Let your boss learn from his own mistakes, don't be afraid to miss deadlines if someone else does not perform." If your boss delays and as a result the deadline is missed, that is *his problem, not yours.*

Answer (score 0):

### Give Earlier Dates / Pad the Schedule

When estimating time to complete a task always include overhead things like waiting for approvals, reviews and other things that will impact your ability to get things delivered on time.  As such if you need 10 days to get a task done you need to add how much time it will take to get their feedback/approval onto that estimate.  This gives you extra days of buffer to tolerate their procrastination without it negatively impacting your work.

How this looks is that you tell your boss not the latest date you need their feedback/approval by, but a date that has been padded.  For example if the drop dead date you need the boss to get their part done is the 21st and it is only the 2nd tell them you need their approval by the 11th.  This gives them some time to procrastinate and do their job without it risking impacting your ability to do your job.

Also make sure that the only dates that your boss sees are the dates you want the boss to care about.  So in the previous example focus on you need their approval for this by the 11th without listing anything about the 21st or that the delivery date for it is the end of the month.